# Regular expression for some custom text

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want validate a custom text entered in textbox using regular expression. I have searched and found some of the stuffs but that are not helping me to achieve my requirement and also I am not much familiar to `javascript` so posting here.

My custom text looks like `mandatory 8 digit numeric then 1 hyphen then at max 2 digit numeric`

`e.g 12345678-12`

But the problem is it should accept multiple text like the above. Which means the text can be like below format:

```
- 12345678-1
- 56543434-91,12349098-4
- 50908909-10,11234568-5
- 50908909-1,11234568-5,0000000-12
and so on.......
```

Any valuable suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the rules of validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(\d{8}-\d{1,2}|,)+/gm
```

here is a demo --> https://regex101.com/r/p6D5rg/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use /g option to match every single coincidence and /m option to match them in multi line.
Something like this should work:

```
var str = "50908909-1,11234568-5,00000000-12";
var coincidences = str.match(/(\d{8}-\d{1,2})/mg);
```

where str.match gets the coincidences of (8 digits)-(1 or 2 digits) codes

And, since we are using the /mg options, it'll match this too:

```
` 12345678-1
- 56543434-91,12349098-4
- 50908909-10,11234568-5
- 50908909-1,11234568-5,00000000-12`.match(/(\d{8}-\d{1,2})/mg);
```